# scheduled task in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a date and time in code, that i want to invoke a specific method. This date and time also might be recurrence.
I will run this on IIS server if that's matter.

Is there a way in C# to do it?

Comment: The simplest solution is to create a console application and schedule it using the Windows Task scheduler. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This topic has been answered a lot of SO, I suggest doing a search to see what has been said before

Comment: I did. all of them referce me to the windows scheduler or to some other frameowrks. I really do need a simple thing.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

I think you would probably need to break your code out into a service of some kind. Running scheduled task isn't what IIS is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool is Visual Cron. I have used this in a production environment and it works great!
http://www.visualcron.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want a [Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer), the ElapsedEventHandler can call functions for you, and they can be set up to reoccur.

Comment: Timer requires to provide him with time in milliseconds. I have DateTime

Comment: TimeSpan timeToDate = yourDateTime - DateTime.Now; then use timeToDate.TotalMilliseconds